# compactness of the space of continuously differentiable functions on a compact set under $L_2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact, say, $X = [0,1]$ for simplicity. Let $C^m(X)$ be the set of all $m$-times continuously differentiable functions on $(0,1)$ such that the derivatives can be continuously extended to $[0,1]$.

**Question:** Is $C^m(X)$ compact under the $L_2$ norm, i.e. $\|f\|_{L_2} := (\int_X f(x)^2 dx )^{1/2}$?

---

**Updated question:** Is the set $\{ f\in C^m(X) : \sup_{x\in X} |f(x)| \leq M \}$ compact under the $L_2$ norm, where $M$ is some constant?

Comment: I think you might be able to spot a continuous function from this space to $\Bbb R$ that's not bounded...

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen The functions in $C^m(X)$ are bounded, since $X$ is compact and functions are continuous. This implies that the $L_2$ norm is well-defined if this is your concern.

Comment: Without a boundedness assumption of some kind, I don't think this can be true. Take for instance the sequence of constant functions $f_n(x) = n$. This contains no convergence subsequence.

Comment: @Chris Thank you! I see the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not compact.  The sequence $\{e_n\}_n$ defined by
$$
e_n(t) = e^{2\pi in t}
$$
lies in your set (with $m=\infty$, and $M=1$) but it has no converging subsequence because
$$\|e_n-e_m\|=\sqrt 2/2,$$ for all $n\neq m$.